# MySQL Query Result Offset With Limit With New Result Possibility?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web-applications, feed

I'm working on an application that uses a scroll load system of 20 or so results loading into a feed at a time as you scroll. This feed consists of constantly added user generated content. Which means the result set can change per query that is offset by X.

So let's say we load 20 results, then scroll, another 20, and then before scrolling more to load the next 20, another user has uploaded a new piece of content, which effectively would present a duplicate in the next set of 20 results for the feed because we're using OFFSET to get additional results, and the total result set is getting shifted by 1 with this addition of new content that falls into the conditions of the query.

What is the best and most efficient way around this? We've dabbled with using the id of a row in a where condition to prevent duplicate results, and only using limit without offset for new results fetched.. so we could do WHERE id < 170 LIMIT 20, WHERE id < 150 LIMIT 20, WHERE id < 130 LIMIT 20, etc.. to control and prevent duplciates... HOWEVER, this does not work in every possible scenario as our result sets aren't always ordered with the id column ordered by DESC..

Soo.. what other options are there?..

Comment: Perhaps fetching the complete result set once, storing it in the users session, and referencing the next 20 results for the feed from the total result set saved to session - which is gaurenteed to stay constant and not include additional user content?

Comment: That depends on your data. I would try the thing above with the growing id and the limit I just would take the biggest or lowes id from the last result. In general I like the idea from your comment, but this takes memory. Let's say you have 10k users and you store for each user 1MB in the session that would take about 10GB of ram.

Comment: With modern browsers, unexpected changes to session variables are more likely than they used to be.  I've been burned by this myself.  That's another reason to minimize the extent to which you rely on session variables.

Comment: Right, the issue with the growing or descending ID approach, is that some of our returned results in the feed, in some situations are ordered by a relevance factor for searching which totally disregards ID ordering, meaning the ordering by descending ID wouldn't present the data in the proper order for a search.

Comment: Also, we can't use a where cause with a descending / growing relevance value, because 2 or more relevance values have the possibility of being the same

Comment: I mean, there has to be a similar solution to this with websites like Pinterest, Tumblr, Facebook and such using the same style for feed loading.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using the `where` clause instead of `limit` with the offset option?  `Limit` can take two arguments.  The `offset` argument seems to do exactly what you want.  For instance:

```
limit 100, 20
```

Takes 20 rows starting at the 101st row.  Then:

```
limit 120, 20
```

Takes 20 rows starting at the 121st row.  (The offsets start at 0 rather than 1 in MySQL counting.)

The one enhancement that you need to make is to ensure that the sort order for the records is *stable*.  A stable sort is, essentially, one where there are no sort keys with the same value.  To make this happen, just make the `id` column the last column in the sort.  It is unique, so if there are any duplicate sort keys, then the addition of the `id` makes the sort stable.

Comment: This approach doesn't work for the situation - my question may not have been clear enough. As the feed loads, what happens if another user uploads a new piece of content that applies to said query? Offset will include a duplicate result in the following query for an additional 20 results with this approach. We don't want that.

Comment: As this new content would introduce a new row with unique id into the result set

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try a database solution.  On the initial request, create and populate a table.  Use that table for the feed.

Make sure the tablename starts with something consistent, like TableToFeedMyApp, and ends with something guaranteed to make it unique.  Then set up a scheduled job to find and drop all these tables that were created earlier than whatever you deem to be a certain interval.

Comment: That seems like the database would get extremely cluttered after a while as there could be 100's of new feed requests per minute, plus I think the overhead for table creation is fairly large in comparison to the other solutions? I could be wrong.